# Add subview by code to a view disappear after re load

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm trying to add a UI Components to my view via code and It works well until I return back to the view (via pop view function) I found that the components add by Interface builder still exists while the components add by the code are removed! (I tried to print the subviews in the VC and they were not exists).

What I'm missing ??

> SharedDataObject.m

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIImageView *brandLogoImageView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UILabel *brandNameLabel;
```

> ViewController.m

```
- (void)initUI {
    if ([[SharedDataObject shared]noLogo]) {
        [[[self view] viewWithTag:13]addSubview:[[SharedDataObject shared] brandNameLabel]];
    }
    else
    {
        [[[self view] viewWithTag:13]addSubview:[[SharedDataObject shared] brandLogoImageView]];
    }

    [_brandMessageLabel setText:[[[SharedDataObject shared] loginObject] promotion]];
}
```

and

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self initUI];
}
```

Comment: do you override any other viewCycle methods like didAppear, willAppear, willDisappear. also whats the code for returning back

Comment: the code is - (IBAction)popViewController:(id)sender {
    [[self navigationController]popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
and I'm override  willAppear, willDisappear

Comment: please show other life cycle methods code too

Comment: Are your componentns initialized... ?

Comment: @David'mArm'Ansermot Sure my components are initialized and they appear while I'm still pushing VCs one by one

Comment: @Shubhank - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
}

Comment: @Shubhank - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [Flurry endTimedEvent:@"selfieScreenOpend" withParameters:nil];
}

Comment: is your view controller extending UIViewController or some other class ?

Comment: @Shubhank No! It doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you are using this view 
`[[SharedDataObject shared] brandLogoImageView]` 
in the viewcontroller you pushed.

UIKit framework only allows one superview for each view. So you need to re-add or use another imageview to display the image in both viewcontrollers.

Comment: That's Right I'm indeed so you mean I need to re-add it a gain on each view I'm navigating in ?

Comment: The best way is not reuse same views in another viewcontrollers. You should re-use the image data, not the view. But yes you need to re-add if you want to use the same view.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your view components in viewDidAppear/viewWillAppear method. means call your initUI method in viewDidApper method of viewcontroller.

Comment: This will work and I've tested it but I want to know why this happen ?!

Comment: because a view cannot have multiple superviews. see my answer below.